# How to find out minimum values of Y given a range of X in a dataset of X,Y values in R?

Tags: r, graph

Suppose for the dataset below:

```
X   Y 
2   10
4   8
6   12
8   5
10  16
12  10
14  14
16  12
18  8
20  5
22  14
24  18
26  2
28  4
30  6
```

Its very easy to find out which is Max or Min value of Y, using `which.max(maydata$Y)` or  `which.min(maydata$Y)`.

I want to find out the values of Y when specific range of X is given. Something like (I know this is not correct syntax):

```
which.min(profile_data1[profile_data1$X1>8 & profile_data1$X1 >20 ][2])
```

Comment: `which.max(df[df$X>5&df$X<14,"Y"])` for example. It returns the index, so if you want the value, you have to nest it into `df$Y[]`

Comment: @Haboryme Thanks for quick reply. this is returning row number and not value of Y. :(

Comment: @Haboryme my guess i can use it... `mydata[which.max( mydata [mydata$X > 5 & mydata$X < 14, "Y" ] ), ][2]`

Comment: See the second part of my comment. `df$Y[which.max(df[df$X>5&df$X<14,"Y"])]` will return the value.

Comment: @Haboryme Thank you so much. yes it helped me to resolve the issue... sometimes, things are pretty easy but look weird... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command to find the maximum value of `Y` given `X > 8 & X < 20`:

```
max(subset(dat, X > 8 & X < 20, select = "Y"))
# [1] 16
```

Here, `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 3):

Xiaotao Luo rigthfully pointed to a mistake, this will output the correct value.

```
df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"][which.max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"])]
```

Explanation because it's becoming long and confusing:
`df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"]` : select all the Y for which 20>X>8
`which.max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"])` : the index of the maximum Y, = **1** here
 `df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"]` : the same subset as before, it's a vector
 `df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"][which.max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"])]` is equivalent to :`df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"][1]` in this case, so we only select the 1st value of the vector.

Sven Hohenstein's solution is more efficient and easier to implement, but hopefully this helps you understand how R indexing works.

Comment: Great comparison. @Haboryme

Answer (score 2):

Try (get row index of max `Y` which `8 < X < 20`):

```
> as.numeric(row.names(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, ])[match(max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, "Y"]), df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, "Y"])])
```

> Result(row index in original data frame):

```
[1] 5
```

If you want the value :

```
> df[as.numeric(row.names(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, ])[match(max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, "Y"]), df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, "Y"])]), "Y"]
```

> Result(value):

```
[1] 16
```

**EDIT:**

To be easier to understand:

```
> Sub.df <- df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20, ]
> Sub.df
   X  Y
5 10 16
6 12 10
7 14 14
8 16 12
9 18  8
> result.index <- as.numeric(row.names(Sub.df)[match(max(Sub.df$Y), Sub.df$Y)])
> result.index
[1] 5
> result.value <- df[result.index, "Y"]
> result.value
[1] 16
```

Comment: Xiaotao Luo Thank you so much for your answer, but in my opinion, the solution by @Haboryme is much easier to understand and implement.

Comment: `df$Y[which.max(df[df$X>5&df$X<14,"Y"])]`

Comment: My mistake, I thought you want the row index in the original data frame of that value.

Comment: But are you sure about the answer? I tried `df$Y[which.max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"])]` and the result is `10` which should be `16`.

Comment: You're right, there is mistake, I forgot that which.max will then output an index from a subset. `df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,]$Y[which.max(df[df$X > 8 & df$X < 20,"Y"])]` will return the correct value.

Comment: I think my answer is so complicated, hoping another simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
max(df[with(df, X>=10 & X<=22),]$Y)
#[1] 16
```

OR using `%in%`:

```
max(subset(df, X %in% 10:22)$Y)
```

OR using `match`:

```
max(df[with(df, !is.na(match(X, 10:22))),]$Y)
```